# c# AutoMapper map different Models to one ViewModel

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, automapper

I have the following Models and ViewModels

Project Model

```
public class Project: BaseModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public int MemberId { get; set; }

    public int ProjectCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Subtitle { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Comments Model

```
public class Comment : BaseModel
{
    public int CommentID { get; set; }

    public int MemberId { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string CommentBody { get; set; }
}
```

ProjectViewModel

```
    public class ProjectViewModel: DonationViewModel
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CommentViewModel> Comments;
}
```

CommentViewModel

```
public class CommentViewModel
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    public string CommentBody {get; set;}
}
```

Mappings

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Project, ProjectViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Comment, CommentViewModel>();
```

I can successfully map project to ProjectViewModel and comments to CommentViewModel but when I try to map CommentViewModel to ProjectViewModel i get a "missing type map configuration" error. What am I missing?

Comment: you didn't show CommentViewModel

Comment: It's the last one..i have a typo in the class name..sorry

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want to map from CommmentViewModel to ProjectViewModel? There are only 2 Properties there and no one has the same name as any Property in ProjectViewModel. If you want to map CommentBody to Body, you should specify it.

Comment: What I want to do is to be able to display a list of Comments in Project page...if i map those 2 properties directly to ProjectViewModel can i "fill" the ProjectViewModel with a list of Comments?

Comment: So you want to map List<CommentViewModel> to ProjectViewModel? You don't need automapper for it, you could just assign property

Comment: Man thank you so much!!!!!! It was so simple...i think it's time for me to have a break!